# sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device

Tags: command-line, mount, python, sudo, chroot

Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS
Gnome

Changed python version which resulted in inability to access Terminal and a few other things.

Used a liveUSB and then selected to try ubuntu.

In that terminal entered:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
sudo mount --bind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
sudo mount --bind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
sudo chroot /mnt/
```

That code executed fine.
I then wanted to change python3.11 to python 3.10 with

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

However I get the error listed in the title. Other attemps with various code to change python also raise the same error. Can't find any similar questions on here.

Comment: You also need to mount `/dev/pts`.

Comment: @muru Normally the devpts is already taken care of by the `/dev` bindmount; manual mounting of a devpts is only required when a devtmpfs is directly mounted into the chroot dev.

Comment: @mcendu for that you need `--rbind`. A regular `--bind` mount like in the question wouldn't necessarily result in submounts being reflected. (`/dev/pts` is a mount of its own, of type `devpts`, `devtmpfs` has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: @muru Ah yes, you are right. This sort of mistake is very easy to make when creating a chroot environment, and so people made `arch-chroot` to easily get over all the pitfalls.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove sudo from the commands.

Comment: In your case running `chroot` with `sudo` in the first place i.e. `sudo chroot /mnt/` will make you `root` in the new `chroot` environment … So, yes no need to use `sudo` there.

Answer (score 3):

[**PTY**(*AKA Pseudoterminal*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) is used for implementing terminal emulators such as [`xterm`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xterm.1.html) … It is involved in enabling the interpretation of passed data in the same way a real terminal would interpret the data … This becomes important when sending input to programs(*such as `su` and `sudo`*) that normally refuse to read input from pipes.

In Ubuntu(*and many other Linux distributions*), PTYs are pseudo-devices identified under [`/dev/pts`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/pts.4.html) and thus a simple `mount —bind` won’t make it available in the target mount-point but, a recursive `mount —rbind` will.

So you can solve this by either mount binding `/dev/` recursively using the option `—rbind` like so:

```bash
sudo mount --rbind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
```

Or by additionally mount binding `/dev/pts/` directly like so:

```bash
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts/ /mnt/dev/pts/
```

Or if you are not going to need such programs as `su` and `sudo` in the target `chroot`, then you can just become the user `root` before you run your commands like so:

```bash
sudo -i
```

Then you’ll be able to run your commands in the same shell with elevated permissions without the need to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens outside of a chroot, then /dev/pts may have been accidentally unmounted. Here is how to mount it:

```
mount none -t devpts /dev/pts
```