# VFS: cannot open root device "nvme1n1p4" or unknown-block

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, kernel, 22.04

I was in the process of upgrading my Ubuntu 20.04 and installing ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately, I made an error during pressing options through the upgrade process. I decided to restart the computer and now I'm unable to log in to Ubuntu. The specific error I encounter is:

VFS: cannot open root device "nvme1n1p4" or unknown-block

[image]

How can I access a terminal under these circumstances?

**Update:**

I can not still login inside ubuntu unless I go to the recovery mode and if I press the normal option it gets stuck here
[image]
I will appreciate if someone could guide me step by step to fix my workstation since it is very important to not mess it up by other mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 and now I don't have a wifi adapter and cannot connect to the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485135/i-upgraded-to-22-04-from-20-04-and-now-i-dont-have-a-wifi-adapter-and-cannot-co)