# I've been trying to upgrade my ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04 jelly for two days straight but whenever the laptop restarts it boots into Initramfs

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, initramfs, dell-vostro

[image]

This issue keeps popping up everytime I try to boot up my laptop after the upgrade

Comment: Your update seems to not have finished correctly and as it appears your new kernel isn't configured correctly ... So you need to either boot using an older kernel and continue the upgrade or you can do that [from a live system USB](https://askubuntu.com/a/1485452/968501)

Comment: Thank you so much  I've been struggling with thus for a week now and it's booted correctly for the first time since then

Comment: Thank you so so much

Comment: You are welcome … I'm happy your system is fixed.