# I want my desktop back

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

I was upgrading from 22.04 to 23.04,  because of audio issues and some 'Depend" results during the start-up process, I was not able to look in to.  The process began with software upgrade informing me a upgrade was available, so I opted to upgrade to 23.04 in hopes that the writers have correct the problem(s). The process went well and I half was through to upgrade when I notice popped up suggest I "re-boot" to clear a problem the install program found. I have never heard of 're-booting' during a install program  and before I could see what was asked of me, the install began and I would have to do my 're-boot' when the upgrade was complete. Then that's when things turned black with a single blinking cursor  in the upper left corner. I waited and waited for the my screen to return to it's familiar form. Yet I was to be shunned by the now solid black screen and when I hit the power button, it shut down faster than , well ,  any pc ever shutdown before. Upon hitting the power button once more- things were happening and what was happening onscreen looked familiar. In a short 3 minutes I would witness the screen ask for my password and go black, never to return in the session. the keyboard was lifeless and the speakers still were lifeless . Something that began after the upgrade to 22.04 a few days ago. There was a word that 23.04 included a fix for the audio and now I am here asking if there is a way to awaken my desktop once more. I could see a among all of the 'OK's" scrolling down that there is six lines which began with "Depend" in red, and I hoped it would not effect the upgrade and as I was not looking at the screen when whatever occurred, bringing me back to the single cursor and black screen.
I was looking at trying to re-install 23.04 from DVD.s I don't know if it can boot from a DVD(s)in it's present  shape.
William

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 and now I don't have a wifi adapter and cannot connect to the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485135/i-upgraded-to-22-04-from-20-04-and-now-i-dont-have-a-wifi-adapter-and-cannot-co)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

A. Boot your PC with the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

B. Open a terminal,

Press Ctrl+Alt+T

C. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a hard drive.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Suppose it informs that / is /dev/sda1, continue running:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste these lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222

nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Ctrl+O Save File

Ctrl+X Close nano

Continue running:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file delete content and paste these lines:

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-backports main restricted universe multiverse

Ctrl+O Save File

Ctrl+X Close nano

Continue running:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
exit
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Well, I'm down to a cell phone as I lost access to the desktop. The suggestion did not work.stppd at network. Don't no what to do. I did get GNU GRUB to come up, no help.What am I to do?? Please I need my desktop back!!

Comment: I was able to boot the os &  start terminal, 'unmount' command is not found. Where do we go from here? Still on cell ph and

Comment: I see there is no 'n' with the unmount command.

Comment: Command is umount

Comment: Yeah, glasses on can help. So I'm in terminal and ata loss as to why the upgrade failed and how to fix it. Too many commands andonly a cell phone

Comment: When I reboot I hit ESC until a boot menu comes up, I redirect to DVD player and hit enter. I keep hitting ESC until GNU GRUB comes up. Choose *advanced options. Pick one with recovery mode and I get a limited OS. Now what's next?

Comment: Takes me to Recovery menu, do all the options and run until I get familiar screen. Sorry I missed a step or 2 above.

Comment: When I did as suggested the unmount command killed sudo and had to reboot to get back to where I was before. So I was working on the suggestion, just got stuck for awhile. Yes it was umount.