# Xubuntu broke after removing the readline-common package

Tags: networking, apt, xubuntu, readline

First of all, I would like to apologize in advance for the little content I can bring to this problem.

My problem is as follows: I'm running Xubuntu 22.04, and I unintentionally removed the `readline-common` package because I had a problem with GCC compiling a program.

Anyway, it literally destroyed my computer, like my internet connection (wifi and wired) stopped working, so I can't reinstall it after that. I downloaded the [`.deb` file of readline-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/readline-common) from the official Ubuntu website.

I rebooted my computer, went into recovery mode, opened a sudo shell from it, and mounted my USB stick manually and did an `apt install` on the previously downloaded deb file.
This worked, but during the installation with apt it tries to retrieve content from the internet.

I can't open a session with the GUI, and I tried to manually launch the internet connection, but I'm stupid and I haven't found the right commands yet.

You must be a bit lost after that, so I don't really have any specific questions at the moment apart from :

1. Do you know of an easy way to solve this problem?
2. If not, do you know of any commands available by default to re-enable the internet either via wired or wireless connection (I know this question will be duplicated).

#### EDIT

After many hours of trying, I finally managed to connect to the internet via ethernet, added the correct DNS, then installed `ubuntu-minimal`, `ubuntu-standard` and `ubuntu-desktop`.
Finally, I resumed the launch. Unfortunately, I'm now running under an interface that strongly resembles Ubuntu, and I'd like to know if you know of a list of default packages from the xubuntu distribution?

This post will be updated to add more information about this.

Comment: You can take the "operation table" path ;)  ... Scary name, but easy method with near 99.99% success rate ... See https://askubuntu.com/a/1485452

Comment: If you have access to another Ubuntu, or from your Live USB, you can try what is listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory

Comment: Do you know where I can find the default packages of the xubuntu distribution?

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/65865/124466

Comment: I would just reinstall at this point.